# RoR: devise gem after edit password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm looking for a similar function
`after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for`
but for the password change `password_path`

after filling the password it is redirected to the url `password_path` (edit password token)

it connects me to the page as if I were logging in but I would like to make a page that redirects and tells it that the password has been changed without logging in

Comment: Have you take a look to the wiki ? https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile

Comment: find `after_resetting_password_path_for`